# javascript removing element by ID only working for latest child element

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

I'm making a dynamic list where users can click a button to remove inputs. When creating new inputs I'm assigning an ID to the child element with a counter that adds 1 every time a new input is generated. But when I try to remove inputs by their ID's, only the latest created input seems to be removable.

I've noticed that if you generate say 5 new inputs, and then click the remove button on say input:2, then it removes the 5th input and button. So even though I'm setting the input and button ID's earlier on in the process, clicking the remove button is relying on the row counter's current value only.

Could anyone give me some pointers as to how to whether old IDs can be pointed to or if I would need to rewrite this in a totally different way? I'm very new to JS so apologies if this is horrendous JS scripting!

```js
var row = 1;

function addFields() {
  row++;

  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "input_" + row
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = "input:" + row;
  container.appendChild(input);

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = "button_" + row;
  button.type = "button";
  button.innerText = "Remove";
  button.onclick = function() {
    remove_field("button_" + row, "input_" + row);
  }
  container.appendChild(button);
}

function remove_field(button_id, input_id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(button_id);
  elem.remove();
  var elem = document.getElementById(input_id);
  elem.remove();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="goal" name="goal">
<button type="button" onclick="addFields()">+</button><br>
<div class="container" id="container" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `row` updates each time you add a new element, so don't directly use `row` to get the id. Directly access `button.id` and `input.id` instead.

```js
var row = 1;

function addFields() {
  row++;

  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "input_" + row
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = "input:" + row;
  container.appendChild(input);

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = "button_" + row;
  button.type = "button";
  button.innerText = "Remove";
  button.onclick = function() {
    remove_field(button.id, input.id);
  }
  container.appendChild(button);
}

function remove_field(button_id, input_id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(button_id);
  elem.remove();
  var elem = document.getElementById(input_id);
  elem.remove();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="goal" name="goal">
<button type="button" onclick="addFields()">+</button><br>
<div class="container" id="container" />
```

Alternatively, get rid of the `remove_field` function entirely and just call `remove` on the variables `input` and `button`.

```js
var row = 1;

function addFields() {
  row++;

  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "input_" + row
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = "input:" + row;
  container.appendChild(input);

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = "button_" + row;
  button.type = "button";
  button.innerText = "Remove";
  button.onclick = function() {
    button.remove();
    input.remove();
  }
  container.appendChild(button);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="goal" name="goal">
<button type="button" onclick="addFields()">+</button><br>
<div class="container" id="container" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Unmitigated . Out of curiosity, does the second method have any downsides over the first one you listed at all? Or is it just better..

Comment: @user8188120 I see no reason why you would need an another function to do this, so personally I would prefer the second way. It would be better to just pass the elements themselves to a function rather than an id if you already have references to the elements, as well.

Comment: Ideally you'd wrap all elements in a container and just remove the container.

Comment: @JavaScript Indeed, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `row` changes on each iteration and your click function merely regards the last value it had. You can either scope it using `let`, `bind` it or just pass the elements to your remove function, which also skips you the the lookups.

```js
//REM: Can remove the row with this solution, just left to show you the issue.
var row = 1;

function addFields() {
  row++;

  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = "input_" + row
  input.type = "text";
  input.placeholder = "input:" + row;
  container.appendChild(input);

  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = "button_" + row;
  button.type = "button";
  button.innerText = "Remove";
  
  //REM: Binding the elements
  //REM: Alternatively you can bind the current value of row.
  button.onclick = function(buttonElement, inputElement, currentRow){
    console.log('This is the value row would have: ', row);
    console.log('This is the value row had at time of binding: ', currentRow);
    
    //REM: Passing the elements to skip any lookup
    remove_field(buttonElement, inputElement)
  }.bind(button, button, input, row);
  
  container.appendChild(button);
}

//REM: Removes a button-input pair
function remove_field(buttonElement, inputElement){
  buttonElement?.remove();
  inputElement?.remove()
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="goal" name="goal">
<button type="button" onclick="addFields()">+</button><br>
<div class="container" id="container" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explained the issue.

I strongly suggest you do not keep a counter.

Here is a delegation version using a div container per row and recommended eventListeners

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const renum = () => {
    container.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').forEach((inp,i) => {
      inp.id = "input_" + (i+1);
      inp.placeholder = "input:" + (i+1);
    });  
  };
  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.matches('.remove')) {
      tgt.closest('div').remove();
      renum();
    }  
  });  
  document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "text";
    div.appendChild(input);
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.classList.add("remove");
    button.type = "button";
    button.innerText = "Remove";
    div.appendChild(button);
    container.appendChild(div);
    renum();    
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="goal" name="goal">
<button type="button" id="add">+</button><br>
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
```

Comment: While this does not explain the issue, it is the way to go for a final solution.

Comment: I agree, thanks so much for this! While the other answers directly answer the question specifically, I will switch to this method.. as from my Python experience I'm aware of how icky counters feel!

Comment: @user8188120 I simplified the code to only give the id and placeholder in the renum function